# How can I test that I've successfully connected to all *five* channels (shell, iopub, hb, stdin, control) of an IPython kernel via SSH when using 2FA?

Tags: ssh, ipython, spyder

I've set up a remote kernel running through SSH to which I connect using my Spyder IDE, and have just added 2-factor authentication (2FA) on the SSH connections using [Duo](https://duo.com) .

Now when I attempt to connect, I get **4** different push notifications, and once I approve some or all of them, Spyder connects and gives me the IPython prompt; and for each attempt below I did approve all **4**.

On my first attempt, it didn't display a result when testing with something like `2+2`
On my second attempt, everything appeared to be working fine.

However, I am aware that there are **5** channels involved (shell, iopub, hb, stdin, control) as I can see on this [Jupyter client doc page](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/client.html).

Is there any way I can, once connected to the remote kernel, test each of the individual **5** channels and check that they are all working properly?

And can you think of a reason why I would receive **4** push notifications rather than **5**? Is it possible that one of the channels isn't used or connected to later on-demand or something like that?

UPDATE: After doing a `netstat` on the server side, I can see that the control channel is not connected, but the other four (shell, iopub, hb, stdin) are. Still unsure what I miss out on by not using the control channel, and whether Spyder provides the same features the control channel by other means; [this page](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html) says:

> Control: This channel is identical to Shell, but operates on a separate socket to avoid queueing behind execution requests. The control channel is used for shutdown and restart messages, as well as for debugging messages.

> For a smoother user experience, we recommend running the control channel in a separate thread from the shell channel, so that e.g. shutdown or debug messages can be processed immediately without waiting for a long-running shell message to be finished processing (such as an expensive execute request).

Comment: How did you setup the remote kernel ? remote_ikernel, enterprise gateway, or custom ? This is likely a complex answer that might be better on the discourse forum, or an issue. You may want to enable debug logging to see when the connections are established. You _should_ be able to have the 5 connections go through a single ssh port forward I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure about the kernel question -- I connect with ```ipython kernel --ConnectionFileMixin.connection_file=C:/myConnection.json --InteractiveShellApp.exec_files=C:/myscript.py```. I just did a netstat on the server side and noticed that it is the *control* channel that is not connected; not sure what features I miss because of that.
And for another mystery -- would Spyder be able to handle 5 connections go through a single ssh port forward? it might be hard-wired that way.
Would you recommend a particular forum to ask this question on? Thanks!

Comment: So you setup the SSH yourself ? Cause the best way to setup via an ssh connection would be https://pypi.org/project/remote_ikernel/ or look into adapting https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-enterprise-gateway/ Which is battle tested for remote connection but usually done for notebook_server. I would as on https://discourse.jupyter.org/ or even on the spyder issue tracker if they have support for enterprise gateway or remote kernels.